# ¿Cómo eliminar index.php en codeigniter en un hosting?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hola a todos tengo un proyecto que lo estoy subiendo a bluehost y tengo problemas con la redireccion de URL :

> sistema/**index.php**/mantenimiento/logistica/adquisicion/producto/registro/clase/

siempre debo agregar **index.php** y eso no es de mi agrado y quiero eliminarlo, pero en el dominio ya tengo otros sub dominios, sera posible elimarlo ?
el archivo .htaccess estoy usando en la carpeta raíz del proyecto.

en el archivo config lo tengo de esta forma:

> $config['index_page'] = '';

```js
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

# Prevent user access to the CI system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 

# Prevent user access to the CI application folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Código htaccess para eliminar el `index.php`

Tener un archivo `.htaccess` en la raíz de la instalación del framework, que suele ser también la raíz del dominio donde estamos trabajando, con un código como el que sigue:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|css|js|images|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Este código redirigirá a todos los archivos que se soliciten a este dominio, menos los que contengan el propio `index.php`, `css`, `js`, `images` o `robots.txt`. La redirección se hará a través de la misma URL, pero agregando `"index.php/"` después del nombre del dominio.

Ahora, sólo nos faltaría decirle a CodeIgniter que, al componer URLs para los enlaces entre las distintas páginas de nuestra aplicación web, no coloque el `index.php`, pues no lo necesitamos.

Esto lo podemos hacer desde el archivo de configuración principal, que están en: `system/application/config/config.php` Simplemente tendríamos que editar la variable de configuración `"index_page"`, poniéndola a la cadena vacía:

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```